# ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.components.items.fill.FillItemData while creating TIBCO map report

Tags: jasper-reports, classnotfoundexception, jaspersoft-studio

I am facing below exception while creating a simple TIBCO map report. I have just dragged a TIBCO map element on the palette and when I see preview then face below exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/components/items/fill/FillItemData
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.tibco.maps.fill.TibcoMapFillFactory.toFillComponent(TibcoMapFillFactory.java:23)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.<init>(JRFillComponentElement.java:72)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.visitComponentElement(JRFillObjectFactory.java:1704)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseComponentElement.visit(JRBaseComponentElement.java:81)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractObjectFactory.getVisitResult(JRAbstractObjectFactory.java:88)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementGroup.<init>(JRFillElementGroup.java:82)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.<init>(JRFillElementContainer.java:89)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.<init>(JRFillBand.java:121)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.getBand(JRFillObjectFactory.java:522)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSection.<init>(JRFillSection.java:74)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.getSection(JRFillObjectFactory.java:498)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:254)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:69)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:57)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:201)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:216)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.<init>(BaseFillHandle.java:74)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AsynchronousFillHandle.<init>(AsynchronousFillHandle.java:97)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AsynchronousFillHandle.<init>(AsynchronousFillHandle.java:86)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AsynchronousFillHandle.createHandle(AsynchronousFillHandle.java:188)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler$5.run(ReportControler.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.components.items.fill.FillItemData cannot be found by com.jaspersoft.studio.tibcomaps_6.2.0.final
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 22 more
```

Can anyone help me out here ?? I have also added Jasper reports JAR to Classpath, but still facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved in JR Lib 6.2.1, soon to be released.

The missing package was added to the OSGI exported packages in the manifest file of the JR Lin JAR.

Thanks,
Teodor

Answer (score 0):

I have used jasper reports some time ago.
Problem is simple ClassNotFound if jar is at class path. them may be your jar version is miss match. Because jasper uses many supporting jar.
so scan your jars once again.
This class (FillItemData) exist in jasperreports-5.1.0.jar
overall you have to check all jars and versions.